# Python: use asyncio module to wait result for 2 independent tasks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

For Python 3.4+, I can use `asyncio` to dispatch independent tasks. 
[image]

Now, I have two long running independent functions. Both functions return result, 
so how do I collect the two results into a single object, using `asyncio` to put 
these two functions inside a IO loop.

```
import asyncio 

async def long_func1():
   await ...
   ...

async def long_func2():
   await ...
   ...
```

Comment: Have you tried `result1, result2 = await asyncio.gather(long_func1(), long_func2())`?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting what you are trying to do...

In order to run both of the function at the same time you can use the [asyncio.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) and [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) for the results of them.

Have a look at the following example:

```
import sys
import asyncio

async def test_1():
    return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name

async def test_2():
    return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name


async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(test_1())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(test_2())

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([t1, t2])
    results = [d.result() for d in done]

    # The order of the finished function is unknown
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

It will run **two** function and will *wait* for both of them to finish.

Once they are `done` it will gather the results of both of the `done` function to the `results` list.